# `akka.pattern.after` - Understanding `duration` Argument?

Tags: scala, akka

Using Scala `2.11.8`, given a `Future` that sleeps `5` seconds before returning `()`, I called `akka.pattern.ask` with a time-out of `1` second:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global 
import akka.pattern.after

val system = ActorSystem.create()

after( FiniteDuration(1, SECONDS),  system.scheduler)( Future{ Thread.sleep( 5000 ); () } )
res15: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = List()

// roughly 5 seconds later, I see:

scala> res15
res22: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Success(())
```

Why doesn't `res15` return a `Failure` since the `Future` does not complete until 5 seconds, however its timeout is 1 second?

Comment: What does this have to do with `ask`?

Comment: Nothing at all, @m-z. I just edited - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`After` method will run your future after some delay. `duration` is not timeout, its the starting delay. `After` method internally uses `scheduleOnce` method of actorSystem schedular.

`After` is very interesting method which starts evaluating/executing your future expression (i.e `value`) only after the certain given duration.

If the given duration is very small then its starts executing the `value` immediately.

As `value` is a call by name parameter the value is not immediately evaluated. `value` will be evaluated only when explicitly called by the name value.

Here is the code from akka lib.

```
def after[T](duration: FiniteDuration, using: Scheduler)(value: ⇒ Future[T])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
  if (duration.isFinite() && duration.length < 1) {
    try value catch { case NonFatal(t) ⇒ Future.failed(t) }
  } else {
   val p = Promise[T]()
   using.scheduleOnce(duration) { p completeWith { try value catch { case NonFatal(t) ⇒ Future.failed(t) } } }
   p.future
}
```

Basically your duration will trigger the following code

```
using.scheduleOnce(duration) { p completeWith { try value catch { case NonFatal(t) ⇒ Future.failed(t) } } }
```

The above code will start executing the future after delay(`duration` is the delay.).

Important observations:

*note that `value` is a call by name parameter. value will be evaluated when called by name that means your future will not be start executing until and unless value is called explicitly. `value` is called inside try because `value` could be a multi line expression which contains lot of code and which returns a future finally.*

*Promise (see in the code) will make you wait in a non blocking fashion till the future is completed its execution. `promise.future` will only complete when given future completes.*